# Inaccurate transformation in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

I am trying to do a simple application in WPF but I am confused because of the unexpected result during the transformation.

I have an Image with OpacityMask set to RadialGradientBrush. RadialGradientBrush has a ScaleTransform with 0.5 coefficient for both axes and center set to the center of an image.

I expect to see an part of the image which has central-symmetry, but its not. The result is symmetrical around horizontal axe but the image mask seems a bit shifted to the left.

I could be happy explaining myself this phenomena with odd/even image size, but that doesn't seems so because the image is rectangular.

What transformation should I use to get an image mask with central symmetry?

Here is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WtfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="940" Width="920">

<Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Width="900" Height="900" Background="Red">
        <Image
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="0"
            x:Name="TopImage"
            Width="900"
            Height="900"
            Source="Images/grid.png" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Image.OpacityMask>
                <RadialGradientBrush Opacity="1">
                    <RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform
                                ScaleX="0.5"
                                ScaleY="0.5"
                                CenterX="450"
                                CenterY="450" />
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                    <GradientStop Color="#ffffffff" Offset="1" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#00ffffff" Offset="1" />
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </Image.OpacityMask>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is a result:

[image]

Here is a link to the sample project: [project here](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/7262767ea989cd595cb4135e40ecc82920141009104300/6ac87289f8d9b7f75ae483d70faecd0d20141009104300/0d1f6e)

Thanks.

Comment: Try testing with a different `Image`... your code works fine for me. Also increase the size of the Window.

Comment: @Sheridan thanks for suggestion, unfortunatelly I need to find a way to make it work with any image.

Comment: My point is that it *does* work... I suggested that you *test* with a different `Image` because it may become more clear that it *is* working. Your displayed `Image` could just be off by a single pixel. Also try setting `SnapsToDevicePixels` to `True` on your `Image`.

Comment: @Sheridan it does not work for me, that is why I started this question. I don't get you - why do you propose to use another image if I need this image? also, as you can see, the SnapsToDevicePixels is already set to True in the example.

Comment: the problem is that your Window width and height are not equal, which means the grid in the window is not centered. You could try to set same width and height for the window, or set the HorizontalAllignment on Grid to Center, so you can see the entire image in the window. I tried out the project you posted and added to the image control 2 extra properties, Stretch="UniformToFill" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality". It looks good on my side.

Comment: @OlimpiuDatcu I don't get it, what is the relation between Window size and the image opacity mask transformation? As far as I understand, the Image Opacity Mask applied to the image in the image-related coordinates, and I had to set them to center with ScaleTransform. Also, the Strech mode I need is Uniform, which is the default one.